# Tomcat - The requested resource () is not available, file mp3

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I just want to finish a simple HTML 5 example.

```
    <audio src="2.mp3" controls autoplay>
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
```

but it can't complete and this is the description from Tomcat:

```
"The requested resource (/DemoPlaying/2.mp3) is not available."
```

My folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

Comment: the relative path to the `2.mp3` in `src` is proper?

Comment: Where in your folder structure is your mp3 residing?

Comment: YES!!yesterday, i used the same path and it ran but today, it got this bug:(

Comment: It's probably _not_ a bug. The error message is pretty clear. The mp3 is not where you think it is. Showing us the folder structure would certainly help.

Comment: my folder structure: http://s10.postimage.org/oayf8263d/Untitled.jpg

Comment: I can't see a file named 2.mp3...

Comment: i just rename it to DemoSong.mp3...when i post this question, it's 2.mp3

Comment: We'll, they're not relative to your html file.

Comment: i write it on jsp file...not html!!

Comment: That would have been useful information to start with. Nevertheless, the issue is the same. The static file is not under the same path as the path requested when fetching your jsp.

Comment: Put your file in `web`.

Answer (score 2):

It's obvious that your mp3 file is not available at the URL you're trying to request it. Correct your 'src' to point to the correct url.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must remember:

1) If your app is wellformed, then the typical structure is like:

```
http://myserver:8080/myapp
```

2) Then your file must be published under the contexto of your app

```
http://myserver:8080/myapp/mp3file
```

3) So, in development time your structure must be:

```
Webcontent
   |
   |--index.jsp
   |--mymp3.mp3
   |--WEB-INF
```

4) And war file must content the same of Webcontent (or root folder of your app)

Only in that way your file will be detectable by the server, and dont forget to registrer the extension on Tomcat Server