# Why Apache Tomcat does not see mp3 file?

Tags: jsf, tomcat, mp3

I develop website that must play music. But tomcat does not see mp3 file that I want to listen.

Here is part of my **internalAccountTemplate.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<f:view contentType="text/html">
    <h:head>
        <title><ui:insert name="title" /></title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body styleClass="defaultStyle" id="body">
        <audio id="customAudio" preload='none'> 
            <source src='templates/KnifeParty.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /> 
        </audio>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

When I press **play** button I get next error message
`/WEB-INF/templates/KnifeParty.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource`

My folder structure:
[image: My folder structure:]

Also I have **NewFile1.xhtml** which work perfectly. But this file (NewFile1.xhtml) I opened in firefox not on Tomcat Server

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Xhtml work</title>
</head>
<body>
    <audio id="yourAudio" preload='none'> <source
        src='templates/KnifeParty.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' /> </audio>
    <a href="#" id="audioControl">play!</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var yourAudio = document.getElementById('yourAudio'), ctrl = document
                .getElementById('audioControl');

        ctrl.onclick = function() {

            // Update the Button
            var pause = ctrl.innerHTML === 'pause!';
            ctrl.innerHTML = pause ? 'play!' : 'pause!';

            // Update the Audio
            var method = pause ? 'pause' : 'play';
            yourAudio[method]();

            // Prevent Default Action
            return false;
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In the web I saw similar problem ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15504123/tomcat-the-requested-resource-is-not-available-file-mp3)) and there people said **registrer the extension on Tomcat Server**

I wrote diffrent path to `KnifeParty.mp3` file and changed his location, but this did not help.

Comment: Please, read about how browser asks for resources in a web request. Firstly, the requested url is evaluated (by JSF) and rendered as proper HTML. Then the browser will try to grab other kind of content, but that's done in a separate request and JSF has nothing to do with it. As @BalusC pointed in the answer, the url to the resource cannot be resolved because the resource not being publicly accessible for the browser. So it's not a problem of tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources in `/WEB-INF` are not publicly accessible. You need to put publicly accessible resources outside `/WEB-INF`. The `/WEB-INF` should only be used for configuration files, template files, include files, tag files, etc which are supposed to *not* be publicly accessible at all.

Once you've moved it into the parent folder of `/WEB-INF` like so,

```
WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |-- WEB-INF
 `-- some.mp3
```

Then you can reference it as below:

```
<audio ...> 
    <source src="#{request.contextPath}/some.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

You can also make use of JSF resource management facility by placing it in JSF dedicated `/resources` folder (which you should already have for JS/CSS/image files) like so,

```
WebContent
 |-- META-INF
 |-- WEB-INF
 `-- resources
      `-- audio
           `-- some.mp3
```

Then you can reference it using `#{resource}` map in EL as below:

```
<audio ...>
    <source src="#{resource['audio/some.mp3']}" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
```

#### See also:

- [Which XHTML files do I need to put in /WEB-INF and which not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9031811/which-xhtml-files-do-i-need-to-put-in-web-inf-and-which-not)
- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-css-js-image-resource-in-facelets-template)

Comment: `src="#{request.contextPath}/some.mp3"` - only this works.     

If my folder structure is [as follows](http://c2n.me/3gSOEen)
and I use `src="#{request.contextPath}/resources/audio/KnifeParty.mp3"` 
I get [next message](http://c2n.me/3gSPrkS).     

In this case `<source src="#{resources['audio/KnifeParty.mp3']}" type="audio/mpeg" />` rendered HTML looks like `<source type="audio/mpeg"></source> `